# Are there stats for Mihstu in 3.5e?

Tags: dnd-3.5e, monsters, content-identification

Does anyone know if there is a 3.5e published version (even in a magazine) of the monster called Mihstu?

There are stats for it for previous (AD&D and OD&D) editions and pathfinder but no stats for 3.5 edition.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

The mihstu is in the *Tome of Horrors* by Necromancer Games for the original unrevised 3rd Edition, and in the *Tome of Horrors Revised* for 3.5e, which to my knowledge had special approval from Wizards of the Coast to update existing official creatures from AD&D. This might be the closest to an official 3rd edition version of the creature.

Comment: I only knew about the ToH Comlete for Pathfinder. I added that detail to my reply.